# Live count emitted elements in rx

Tags: rx-java, system.reactive, reactive-programming, rx-android

Is there any way of counting the amount of elements that have already been processed in a stream in RxAndroid?

I am having something like that:

```
Observable.fromArray(new String[]{"these", "are", "my", "values", "."})
            .map(s -> doSomeCoolStuff(s))
            // ...
            .subscribe(amountOfProcessedItems -> Log.d("test", "" + amountOfProcessedItems));
```

And I am looking for something so that my output would look like `1 2 3 4 5`, basically after each item count the amount of items that have already been emitted.

Comment: I understood that there is a `mapWithIndex` method specifically to do what you ask. Just replace your `map` call.

Comment: FYI: `mapWithIndex` isn't part of RxJava: it's in https://github.com/davidmoten/rxjava-extras

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just count the elements:

```
AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
Observable.fromArray(new String[]{"these", "are", "my", "values", "."})
        .map(s -> doSomeCoolStuff(s))
        // ...
        .subscribe(dummy -> Log.d("test", "" + counter.incrementAndGet()));
```

Edit: If you just want to convert elements to increasing integers, here's how:

```
sourceOservable
.zipWith(Observable.range(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE), (any, counter) -> counter)
.whatever(...)
```

Comment: :D Okay that was simple. But I would really prefer to convert this into a stream of integers and not do the counting after subscribing. Is that possible at all?

Comment: Look at [Observable.reduce()](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#reduce(rx.functions.Func2))

Comment: Just remember this might lockup your thread, so I would subscribe off of your Main/UI thread.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [scan](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/scan.html) as well

```
        Observable
            .just("One","Two","Three","Four")
            .scan(1,(counter,string) -> ++counter)
            .subscribe(item -> Log.i(TAG,item.toString()));
```

Comment: This solution only works for `Flowable` and `Observable` streams.